Where did it come from: an etymology puzzle
You know these.  This not a test of trivia, these are simple words every 2nd-grader knows, you just have to remember you know them.

The medical assistive device with the same name as the woody grass from which it was originally made
The cleaning device with the same name as the shrub from which it was originally made
The cleaning device with the same name as the sea animal from whose skeleton it was originally made
The container with the same name as the tree from whose wood it was originally made
The article of personal hygiene with the same name as the gourd from which it is made

(If it helps, all the words are six letters or fewer.)
Many thanks to Kate Gregory for #5.


The medical assistive device with the same name as the woody grass from which it was originally made


 Cane


The cleaning device with the same name as the shrub from which it was originally made


 Broom


The cleaning device with the same name as the sea animal from whose skeleton it was originally made


 Sponge


The container with the same name as the tree from whose wood it was originally made


 Box


Excellent.  I am hoping to collect more examples of these kinds of words.

rot13(ybbsnu) is a plant / cleaning device

@KateGregory — thanks, added.

@MichaelLorton As Kate Gregory wrote, #5 is a plant (a gourd), not a sea animal.

@JaapScherphuis — huh.  Live and learn.
